# Syntax for using {{ article.image }} inside {% static %} with django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Trying to display an image on a webpage with django templates

```
{% for article in article_roll %}
    <li><div class="blog-post" id="blog{{ forloop.counter }}">
        {% load static %}
        <img src="{% static '{{ article.image }}' %}" alt="{{ article.alt }}">
        <div class="blog-post-preview">
            <span class="blog-title">{{ article.image }} {{ article.title }}</span>
            <span class="blog-date">{{ article.date }}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="blog-text">{{ article.preview }}</span>
    </div></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the part that's giving me trouble

```
<img src="{% static '{{ article.image }}' %}" alt="{{ article.alt }}">
```

{{ article.image }} is an ImageField in an SQLite Database setup with the default configurations django has.  My main concern is loading up the correct image for each article as the for loop progresses, but I can't even get {{ article.image }} to evaluate to anything useful within the {% static %} braces.

the static url comes out as

```
<img src="/static/%7B%7B%20article.image%20%7D%7D" alt="image thing">
```

When what I'm trying to get is

```
<img src="/static/value_of_{{article.image}}" alt="image thing">
```

I've tried escaping characters, avoiding using ' ', and rewriting the urls.

I feel like I might be approaching this problem entirely wrong and there's a better way to do it, but I've been looking through the documentation and haven't seen anything obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `'{{ }}'` inside the static tag.

```
<img src="{% static article.image %}" alt="{{ article.alt }}">
```

Comment: Yup, that's what it was.  Thank you!